# What is the type of _id index in MongoDB hashed or b-tree?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

Could anyone tell me what is the type of index used by MongoDB for the _id field? whether it is hashed or a b-tree index. I have tried going through the documentation, but could not find any concrete information

Thank you
Moditha

Comment: b-tree. All indexes are, even hashed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They use b-tree, it is specified here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/#b-tree